# Want to map zoomed image coordinates with actual image coordinates in android imageview

Tags: android, touchimageview

I am currently using this gitup touchimageview https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView library.... After zoom,based on the zoom percentage I want to map the longpress coordinates to original image coordinates. Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try to get matrix of `ImageView`:

```
float[] values = new float[9];
getImageMatrix().getValues(values);
```

With this array, you have position of top-left corner in terms of image on indexes 2 and 5. For example, when `values[2], values[5]` is -10,-10 it means, that left top corner of screen is 10,10 pixel of image. So, you can get coordinate of long press:

```
float imageX = (pressX - values[2])/scale;
float imageY = (pressY - values[5])/scale;
```

Recently I work with zoomed images, and use this library: https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView
I think its a bit better, it have some predifined touches with image coordinates, and is still improved (last commit ~2 months ago)

Comment: 1) `getImageMatrix()` 2) invert returned `Matrix` 3) call `mapPoints` on inverted `Matrix`, for a reverse mapping skip step 2)

Comment: Can you please share me detailed tutorial of this solution?